# connecting Vaadin app to Mysql on EC2 server

Tags: mysql, jdbc, amazon-ec2

I'm moving a Vaadin application from my local environment to an EC2 server. It has a mysql database to which I currently connect using the code:

```
connectionPool = new SimpleJDBCConnectionPool(
                "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver",
                "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/" + dbName, dbUser, dbPassword, 2, 50);

        connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/" + dbName, connectionProperties);
        statement = connection.createStatement();
```

Now I understand that all that I should do is change "localhost" for my server IP but it is not working... I'm have mysql correctly working on the server, and I even using phpmyadmin without any trouble...

I get the error:

> Communications link failure: The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.

Any ideas on what is wrong?

Comment: Where is your mysql server located? On the same EC2 host?

Comment: I have removed the vaadin-tag. It is not related to the problem at hand.

Comment: If the DB is on the very same server as your application, then localhost is the correct way to access it.

Comment: Thanks @AndréSchild ...while developing, I have the app in my computer and the DB in the server...how should it be then? using the IP?

Comment: In that case you need the public IP of your server and you also need to configure the EC2 Firewall to allow access from the internet to your MySQL Server

Comment: How can I configure the firewall for that @AndréSchild ? ...thanks for all your help

Comment: Read the aws ec2 docu or Google for it. It's Not complicated, but be aware that every internetuser could try to Login ..